# Webpack configuration for TS + random js to pack

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a legacy project where I'm slowly introducing TS. The same project also defines a couple of random JS files. I would like to bundle the transpiled TS => JS + a couple of JS files into one output bundle.

As I'm a total noob when it comes to webpack, I have this setup for now:

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    entry: "./typescript/app.ts",
    devtool: 'source-map',
    output: {
        filename: "app.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/js/build")
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx', '.json', '.css', '.scss'],
        modules: ['typescript', 'src/js', 'node_modules']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                include: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'typescript')],
            },
            {
                test: /script\.main\.js/,
                include: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/js')],
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

for a project structure like

./node_modules
./typescript (for new typescript files)
./src/js/build (for webpack output)
./src/js/*.js for files I'd like to pack additionally

However, the second rule doesn't seem to be taken into account in that the specified file `src/js/script.main.js` is not bundled.

Changed the modules to

```
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                include: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'typescript')],
            },
            {
                test: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/js/script.main.js'),
            }
        ]
    }
```

but also didn't help

Comment: Do you import those js files anywhere? I believe Webpack will only bundle the entry file and all the direct and indirect imports from it. So you need to have these .js files imported by the entry file or have another entry point added to the Webpack configuration (webpack supports multiple entrypoints: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/entry-context/#entry)

Comment: @ncpa0cpl I don't really have a reason to import the other file as it doesn't export anything. However, multiple entries might be a good thing to look into - but from what I could tell this results in one bundle per entry - can they be merged?

Comment: I am not that familiar with Webpack, but you can import these files even if those do not export anything, you can just omit the `from` part in the import like this: `import "path/to/the/file";`